# Global KTable storage limitations

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

What is the limit that GLobalKTable can store? Is it possible to store 50 millions mappings from long to long in GLobalKtable? How to configure the kafka-streams properly to do it?
Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 2):

Only your local disk is your limit. Check out the capacity planning guide to learn how to estimate the required storage: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html